# Display the preselected data in the dropdownlist

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Goal:
When the modal appear based on selected row, the selected dropdownlist with preselected data, from month, based on the users data about month will display in the dropdown list.
For instance Josef's data 'bout month is value 2 and in the dropdownlist the first data that will appear is 'Feb'

Problem:
What is needed to be changed in the source code in order to achieve the goal?

Stackblitz:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-sihvnq?file=src/index.js

Info:
*I'm newbie in Reactjs

Comment: I tried running your code on Stackblitz. When I click on `Open Modal` it throws an error that select is not defined. Probably you have not imported a Select component in the index.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not setting the value for your select.
Im guessing that you are using the component `react-select`.

So when you change your select to this code, everything should work es expected:

```
          <Select
            defaultValue={options.filter(option => option.value === openItem.startMonth)}
            name="startMonth"
            options={options}
          />
```

when you want that your state is updated, you need replace `defaultValue` to `value` and pass to your Select-Component an `onChange` function.

Here is a working example:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-pq1mnu?file=src/index.js